# Locating Hyperlinks in documents without opening them

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-word, microsoft-powerpoint, hyperlink

Is there any chance of locating hyperlinks in a documents without opening them? My friends and I have been working on a project with roughly 300 to 400 documents including MS Word, Excel and PowerPoint files. We are supposed to locate all the hyperlinks and URL within the documents to make some amendments due to our company's policy changes.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not aware of a way too "view" the documents without actually viewing them, unless you found a software too do so such as Link Checker (https://www.ablebits.com/word-links-checker/index.php).

Good luck, though

Answer (score 0):

As Xaxis said, you can do this using a tool and my favorite is a free software called [AstroGrep](http://astrogrep.sourceforge.net/). It searches in the location you choose, in all files a certain keyword/phrase. And as you will see in the screenshot below it also shows you the line where you can find that keyword.

[image]

Comment: Thanks, let me have a look into the software. Appreciate your help so much!

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there's any way of listing hyperlinks w/o opening the document, but since all of the Office apps can be automated, external programs can do the work for you (and at least in the case of Powerpoint, could change the links for you as well, so long as the links you're starting with and the one you want to change to have a consistent pattern.  If there's someone on staff with a moderate amount of VB/VBA/.Net knowledge, it shouldn't be too difficult to cook up a tool to do this, at least for PPT.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I am not good with VB/VBA/.Net knowledge that's why I am currently looking for any software which can help me with these.